# VBA Macro not detecting Interior or Font Color properly

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, visual-studio-macros

I have some VBA code which works on two columns: Column A and Column B. Basically, it loops over Column B, and tries to find each Column B value in Column A. Additionally, some values in Column A have a Cell (Interior) color of Blue.

So there can be 3 outcomes:

1. If a Column B value is NOT found in Column A, then that Column B value has its Cell (Interior) color set to Red.
2. If a Column B value IS found in Column A, and the value in Column A has a Blue Cell (Interior) color, then that Column B value has its Cell (Interior) color set to Yellow.
3. If a Column B value IS found in Column A, and the value in Column A does NOT have a Blue Cell (Interior) color, then that Column B value has its Cell (Interior) color set to Green.

Point 1 works, however the IF check for separating Points 2 and 3 doesn't work. All such cases go to Point 3 automatically.

Can someone identify the problem ?

Code:

```
Sub Looper()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Sel As String
Dim MoveDown As String
Dim sourceVal As String
Dim Program As String


Dim i2 As Integer
Dim MoveDown2 As String
Dim Sel2 As String
Dim destVal As String
Dim found As Boolean


i = 2

MoveDown = "YES"

MoveDown2 = "YES"
i2 = 2

Do Until MoveDown = "DONE"
    Sel = "B" + Replace(Str(i), " ", "")
    sourceVal = Range(Sel).Value
    If Range(Sel).Value = "" Then
        MoveDown = "DONE"
    Else
        MoveDown2 = "YES"
        i2 = 2
        found = False
        Do Until MoveDown2 = "DONE"
            Sel2 = "A" + Replace(Str(i2), " ", "")
            destVal = Range(Sel2).Value
            If Range(Sel2).Value = "" Then
                MoveDown2 = "DONE"
            Else
                If destVal = sourceVal Then
                    If Range(Sel2).Interior.Color = vbBlue Then
                        Range(Sel).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Else
                        Range(Sel).Interior.Color = vbGreen
                    End If
                    found = True
                End If
            End If
            i2 = i2 + 1
        Loop
        If found = False Then
            Range(Sel).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: are the cells manually colored blue or is it the result of conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine and does what you would expect it to do, however I see two potential problems here

1. what happens when a `sourceVal` finds two or more matching `destVal` ... a blue `destVal` will set `sourceVal` yellow, but a subsequent non-blue match will turn it back to green unless you `Exit Loop` after `found = True`
2. in Excel 2010 blue is not blue !!! When you shade a cell by hand, even when the tooltip suggests  blue, it is not really blue in the sense of `vbBlue` .... check this by `Debug.Print Range(Sel2).Interior.Color`

[image]